# How do I remove whitespace to balance?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, whitespace

I just started Python as my first language two and a half weeks ago so please bear in mind that I probably took the longest route to create this code. That in mind, any advice you have for the rest of the code is greatly appreciated.

Anyways, on to my question: I'm trying to get everything to line up nicely regardless of the item_name the user enters. Of course, the longer a name the user enters, the farther it pushes the rest of the line. Does anyone have any advice to remove a certain amount of whitespace depending on the length of item_name? I've never posted code like this before so I might not do it right, but here's the specific print section for what I'm having issues with:

```
for i in range(0, loop_num):
print('Item %d: %s               $%.2f    %d     $%.2f' % (
     item_counter , 
     item_name_list[i] , 
     item_price_list[i] , 
     int(item_quantity_list[i]) , 
     single_item_total[i] 
     ))
item_counter += 1
```

Here's the first half of the code before the above:

```
    item_name_list = []
item_price_list = []
item_quantity_list = []
single_item_total = []
loop_num = int(input('Enter how many different unique items you have total \n'))
item_counter = 1

for i in range(0, loop_num):
    item_name = input('Please enter the name of item %d: ' % item_counter)
    item_name_list.append(item_name)
    item_price = float(input('Please enter the price of item %d: ' % item_counter))
    item_price_list.append(item_price)
    item_quantity = float(input('Please enter the quantity of item %d: ' % item_counter))
    item_quantity_list.append(item_quantity)
    item_counter += 1
```

I won't give the final section because that's simply me printing the subtotal, tax, and grand total. Here's the output when I enter 3 items with same number of characters in the name:

```
RECEIPT                                                                                                                                              

        Name               Price Quantity Total                                                                                                     
Item 1: Milk               $3.99    1     $3.99  
Item 2: Eggs               $2.00    4     $8.00                                                                                                      
Item 3: Soda               $4.00    3     $12.00                                                                                                     

Subtotal    $23.99                                                                                                                                   
Sales tax   $1.20                                                                                                                                    
Grand Total $25.19
```

If I enter any character different from the others, the prices and quantities get pushed around. If it's too complicated to do, just tell me. I just hate having them not be able to line up.

Comment: You should read about the `format()` function(s). It is meant to replace the `%` formatting and provides helpful features.

Comment: My university course taught me to use %s %d etc. I'm assuming that's outdated but I still see some people use it. Is this specifically why you told me to look at it?                                                                                                         <   :  left-align text in the field
^   :  center text in the field
>   :  right-align text in the field

Comment: Right, this makes things much easier.

Comment: Nevermind, I see why the further I got down on the page that explains them. Most of it looked so similar to what % did that I was wondering what the point was. Thank you so much for telling me this! Saved me a huge headache.

Comment: Want to mark your comment as solving this but the green checkmark isn't appearing next to your comment. There's no upvoting button or anything either. Is it because I'm a new user?

Comment: A comment doesn't have a checkmark, only real answers have (like the one I created now). Comments can be upvoted with enough reputation but this upvote doesn't count for the reputation of the person who commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `format()` function and its [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) are a better way to format strings than the old `%` formatting.

In this case the align characters `<` and `>` can help and the output code becomes something like:

```
print('Item {}: {:<15} ${:.2f} {:>4}     ${:.2f}'.format(...)
```